# RecycleView works fine for the first time ,next time it shows nothing?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-recyclerview

RecycleView works fine in the first time on my "home" Activity, but when i go to another activity (through the navigation menu) and comeback to "home" Activity the recycle view don't show anything ?

the items in that my recycleview shows are a linearlayouts (user_row.xml), when i use log.e i can see that the data is there but the recyleview fails to list the items (in the second time)

- The home activity :

```java
package com.example.forum;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    //Variables
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        //HOOKS OF NAVIGATION MENU
        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);


        //DATA AND RECYCLERVIEW
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        adapter = new  ForumAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        //TOOL BAR
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        //NAVIGATION MENU
        navigationView.bringToFront();
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout , toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open,R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.nav_home:
                Intent intent33 = new Intent(Home.this,Home.class);
                startActivity(intent33);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_user:
                Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this,Myprofile.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_logout:
                SessionManager sessionManager = new SessionManager(Home.this);
                sessionManager.logout();
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(Home.this,Login.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

- The home xml :

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    tools:context=".Home"
    tools:ignore="ExtraText"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:menu="@menu/main_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="start"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="675dp"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.006"
                app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_action_menu"
                app:title="Home"
                app:titleMarginBottom="10dp"
                app:titleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                app:titleTextColor="#00BCD4" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/aldrich"
                android:text="@string/ensak_business_forum"
                android:textColor="#E4E4E4"
                android:textColorLink="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayoutxxx"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:translationY="130dp"
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="175dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:background="#00FFFFFF"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recycler_view">

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="#00FFFFFF"
                    app:cardElevation="0dp">

                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="#00FFFFFF"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
                    app:cardElevation="0dp">

                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

- The view row (user_row.xml) :

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutxxx"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounding_relative_layouts"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:padding="10dp">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/firstcardxxx"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/imagelayoutxxx"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView4xxx"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/secondcardxxx"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/infoslayoutxxx"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4xxx"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/aldrich"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button4xxx"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/textView4xxx"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_green_button"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/aldrich"
                    android:text="VIEW MORE"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textColorHighlight="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button5xxx"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/button4xxx"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_red_button"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/aldrich"
                    android:text="SUBSCRIBE"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

- The home page :
  [The home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziSdd.png)
- the menu :
  [The menu :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpqBq.png)
- when i go to another activity :
  [when i go to another activity :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXdyB.png)
- when i come back through menu :
  [when i come back through menu :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXCPo.png)

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because all of your logic is inside the `onCreate()` method of the Home activity. `onCreate()` is only invoked once when an activity is created.

Activities are kept on the activity stack, with the most recent activities being at the top of the stack.

In your case, the Home activity is placed into a stopped state while the other activity is active.

When you navigate back to the Home Activity, `onCreate()` is not called because it is already created. In this case `onRestart()` is called followed by `onStart()`.

My suggestion is to move the code for the `RecyclerView` in `onCreate()` to `onStart()`.

You should read about the Activity Lifecycle [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle).

And for future reference, there is also a Fragment Lifecycle which is slightly different. You can read about the Fragment Lifecycle [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle).

Comment: thanks @RStevoUK for your help i checked and i did read the Activity lifecyle, i moved the code to onStart (since its when the user navigates to the activity again) but still it's not showing the views , the weird thing is that data is there, when i call recycler view i automatically call the adapter (i still get the data even on second time but onCreateViewHolder and onBindViewHolder both of them they are not called in the second time i acces the Home activity)

Comment: Also @RStevoUK i did this for checking the activity current states, i crated all the functions (onStart , onResum ...) then i put log messages inside of each function, ex : inside onStart, i putted a log message that says : im inside onStart...etc , then i found out that when i quit the home activity from the menu and go back to it actually the app is onStop then it goes back to onCreate that means "the app process killed" , wich mean, it doesn't go to onRestart then to onStart .... i guess the problem is my bad architecture  :(

Comment: Yes, it sounds like it. From looking at your code there doesn't seem to be a problem but it's difficult when I can't debug it. Try following a tutorial but still use your data. I still can't see why the data wouldn't be populated every time though. Keep trying though, this is what programming is all about. It's like a continuous cycle of getting stuck on a problem for days, solving the problem, getting stuck on another problem for days.

Comment: XD  definitely it is, i will continue reading the documentation, thank you soo much for your help

Answer (score 1):

I found the response to my question, so i'll just share the answer in case any one faces the same problem, the problem i had is that the activity launches with no data in it, i thought the problem was from the recycler view or from the layout manager, but actually the problem was so simple i just have to wait for the data to download first!, if the activity life starts and the data hasn't been loaded yet it will show nothing, so i added a simple ----- WAIT() ----- function to dellay the data loading first then the data can be bined to recycler view and so on ...